# How to restart IIS app pool on a remote machine in powershell using the cmd line?

Tags: powershell, iis, restart, pool

I've trying to automate recycling the IIS AppPool on a remote machine. I've got 99% of the script working, except I'm stuck at recycling/restarting the app pool on the remote server.

When I run the following command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName dwintvs  -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command:"%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd" ("&") start APPPOOL "ProAPI"}
```

I keep getting the error:

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'start'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
    + PSComputerName        : dwintvs
```

I get the same error if I try a restart or stop.

Any thoughts anyone what I'm missing?

I also tried the `|` and `&` but I get more errors.

Comment: enclose the command in single quotes, or escape the other quotes. Any reason you're using `Invoke-Expression`?

Comment: not sure if this would help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/restart-webapppool?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: Hi Abraham, no reason, it just worked ;) i'm stuck at that part. I tired the single ' but nothing changed ;(

Comment: Hi – jspcali ast week, it's an older version of ps and doesn't recognize the command and i cannot downlaod the webadmin module :( 
thanks though!

Comment: If the remote system is running IIS it should be installed on that system already. So you can do something like `Invoke-Command -ComputerName dwintvs -ScriptBlock {Import-Module WebAdministration; Restart-WebAppPool -Name ProAPI}`

Comment: thanks Madtechnician!

will give it a try and let you know ;)

Answer (score 1):

Tested on Server 2019 with PS 5.1

All I did is cleaning up the command line a little bit.

This does not require **webadministration** module as it uses the classic IIS management utility:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName dwintvs -ScriptBlock { c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd start APPPOOL "ProAPI" }
```

Note I was not able to get an environment variable in there so hardcoding the path to **appcmd**

Comment: thanks Alex, that worked as well!!! , difference is when i run your command i get a reply with service started or not, Madtechnician works too but i have to refresh IIS to see if it stopped, both are great ways to do it, thanks again!!!

Comment: Great! It works. I've just replaced "start" with "recycle".